# @Pattern annotation for a method parameter

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-validator

I am trying to validate a emailId which is part of a method parameter and a Query param for the rest endpoint. Using the @Pattern annotation in the method parameter is not working. Is there a better way to handle this scenario using annotation

```
public EmailResponse isEmailRegistered(HttpServletRequest request,
         @RequestParam("emailId") @Valid @Pattern(message = "Email is invalid", regexp = "^.+@.+\\..+$") final String emailId)
```

I tried the above and it does not work. Because the email Id field is query parameter I cannot wrap it in a object and add validator on it.

I tried wrapping it in a wrapper object as below but to no luck

```
public EmailResponse isEmailRegistered(HttpServletRequest request,
         @RequestParam("emailId") @Valid final EmailIdWrapper emailId, final BindingResult bindingResult)
```

EmailId Wrapper class

```
public class EmailIdWrapper implements Serializable{

@NotNull(message = "Email Id is required")
@Size(min = 5, max = 50, message = "Invalid length for email")
@Pattern(message = "Invalid email id", regexp = "^.+@.+\\..+$")
private String emailId;

public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
```

}

With this case I get a conversionnotsupported error which is quite obvious as the url parameter is a string and I am assigning to a object.

Comment: Is this method part of a Spring MVC controller or something else? If so then what is `@QueryParam` (JAX-RS?).

Comment: Yes its part of spring MVC controller and @QueryParam is used to denote URL query parameters

Comment: Why are you using something that isn't by default support? You can simply bind it to an object (create a property `emailId`) put the `@Pattern` on it and `@Valid` on the method. That is basic Spring MVC support, and I have never seen the `@QueryParam` I now `@RequestParam`..

Comment: QueryParam is JAX-RS annotation and RequestParam is spring mvc annotation. I have changed it RequestParam. Thanks for that but it still does not solve my issue as its a String and I cannot wrap it in a object as its a url parameter

Comment: Instead of thinking that you cannot do something try it as it will work. As mentioned just create an object with a property `emailId` as mentioned earlier. Spring will bind the request parameter to it. So yes you can wrap it in an object (I strongly suggest a read of the Spring Reference guid eon how Spring MVC works).

Comment: @M.Deinum I did try it and it does not work. Can you please have a look at my edits? Its a URL paramter which I am trying to validate and not a path variable. Path variables can be assigned to wrapper object but I could not find a way for URl parameters to be assigned. If you are sure your solution is different to what I tried and it works could you please share the same?

Comment: Again URL parameters can be bound, as suggested read the documentation. `@RequestParam` is parameter (from form or URL), `@PathVariable` is different beast and you are mixing those up. Don't annotate the argument with `@RequestParam` use `@ModelAttribute` no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but
have you tried putting

> @Validated

in the Controller class level?